I can not instantiate my Student class in Program.cs
I have a Student class in my console application like this :
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    public class Student
    {
        public Student(Student student)
        {
            StudentId = student.StudentId;
            FullName = student.FullName;
        }

        public int StudentId { get; set; }
        public string FullName { get; set; }
        
    }
}

It has a copy constructor in its body and when I want to instantiate it in the Program class like this:
Student student = new Student();

I will have an error that

"There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal
parameter 'student' of 'Student.Student(Student)'"

When I can not instantiate my Student class how could I pass the argument of Student to its constructor ?
I want to instantiate my Student class but I've got the error on it that I described.

Have you looked at constructor overloading already?

You did not define a default constructor (one that gets no arguments), so new Student() cannot work. What do you expect the Student fields to hold in this case ?

In C#, classes do have an implicit default constructor, unless you define a constructor yourself (which you did), then you also have to define the default (parameterless) constructor explicitly.

You mean that I have to add another constructor to my Student class ?

Yes, a default one (without parameters). And you should probably set the fields to some meaninful default value in it.

but I want to instantiate my class with copy constructor, Can you answer it with a code sample ?

In order to copy you need a Student to copy from (and pass it to the copy constructor, e.g.: new Student(someOtherStudent)). You don't have such another student in your code.

If you are using Properties as Public you can instance like a Student student = new Student() {
StudentId = student.StudentId;
FullName = student.FullName;
}
without overload constructor.

You mention that you would like to use a copy constructor to create a new Student.
This requires you to have an existing Student instance to copy from.
Moreover - as long as you only have a copy constructor you will never be able to create such an instance (because the implicit default constructor will no longer be available).
The solution is to add a constructor - either a default one (without parameters), or one that requires e.g. an int and a String and initializes the fields of the new instance:
// Default constructor:
public Student()
{
   StudentId = -1;        // some default ID
   FullName = "SomeName"; // some default name
}

Or:
// Constructor with parameters:
public Student(int id, String name)
{
   StudentId = id;
   FullName = name;
}

(or even both).
Note that if you use the default constructor you should probably set the fields to proper values afterwards.
Only after creating an instance with such a constructor you can use your copy constructor:
// Create a default instance and then set the fields:
Student studentToCopyFrom = new Student();
studentToCopyFrom.StudentId  = 111;
studentToCopyFrom.FullName = "Joe";
// Or create an instance with arguments for the fields:
Student studentToCopyFrom = new Student(111, "Joe");

// Now create a new instance with the copy constructor:
Student student = new Student(studentToCopyFrom);


If you need a copy-constructor, use a record type, which already has one by default:
public record class Student(int StudentId, string FullName);

Usage example:
var student2 = student1 with { StudentId = 42 };


As far as I know a proper copy-constructor is one that accepts an exitsing instance to copy from (not the value for the fields). See here.

@wohlstad Yes, and records have an implicit one, so you could basically just do var student2 = student1 with {} to create a 1:1 copy (also there is no real benefit in doing that, if the type is immutable)

I see. Good to know. As for the benefit - the OP asked for it specifically, I assumed for educational purposes, and so I answered accordingly.

@wohlstad I figured the point that confused them was that they couldn't use the default constructor anymore, that's what I addressed in my comment. The info about records is just in addition to the other answers.

You might be right. I added an explicit note about that to my answer to clear up any confusion of the sort you mentioned.

As soon as you wrote some kind of constructor - in your case the copy constructor,
then the default constructor is deleted,
And so when you do: Student student = new Student();
It has no empty constructor to refer to.
Your solution is to simply create a default constructor that initializes the parameters with the default you choose
public Student()
    {
        StudentId = 0;//for example
        FullName = "Jhon Doe";//for example
    }

